# Hive query manipulation for missing data not produced on non-business days (weekends & holidays)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I've a query regarding some tweaking my Hive query in the requirement defined below; couldn't get my head around on this.

Case: The data gets generated only on business days i.e., weekdays & non-holidays dates. This data I load in Hive. The source & target, both are HDFS.

Stringent process: The data should be replicated for every day. So, for Saturday & Sunday, I'll copy the same data of Friday. Same is the case for public holidays.

Current process: As of now I'm executing it manually to load weekends' data.

Requirement: I need to automate this in the query itself.

Any suggestions? A solution in spark for the same is also welcome if feasible.

Comment: But he may access Hive from Spark SQL. @Knowone  I offer a solution we implemented only just recently.

Comment: Thanks @thebluephantom. I implemented the same. Teradata DB also has the same approach of using the calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though clear what the issue is, it is unclear when you say " in the query itself".

Two options

1. When querying results, look for data using a scalar sub query (using Impala) that looks first for the max date relative to a given select date i.e. max less than or dqual to given seldct date; thus no replication.
2. Otherwise use scheduling and when scheduled a) check date for weekend via Linux or via SQL b) maintain a table of holiday dates and check for existence. If either or both of the conditions are true, then copy from the existing data as per bullet 1 whereby select date is today, else do your regular processing.

Note you may need to assume that you are running processing to catch up due to some error. Implies some control logic but is more robust.